# Codeigniter failed login direct access to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

i have login form, and then i try to access the controller directly, it works ! how do i prevent this access ?

i got some class

```
class C_home extends CI_Controller{

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->session->set_userdata('islogin'); //to set session islogin
}

function index()
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('islogin') != TRUE) 
    {
        redirect('c_home','refresh'); //caused infinite refresh
    }
        redirect('c_login', 'refresh');
}
}
```

then i try to direct access controller, the page show infinite refresh, i want the page to show the login form

how do i resolve this ?

Comment: Generally its better to have a whole different function for login if not controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd rather do this like so

```
class C_home extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function index()
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('islogin') != TRUE) 
    {
        redirect('c_home/login','refresh'); // go for login
    }

    // do something for loged in users here

}

function login()
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('islogin') == TRUE) 
    {
        redirect('c_home','refresh'); // get back home
    }

    // perform some login logic here
    // then, if successful
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('islogin',TRUE);
        redirect('c_home','refresh'); // get back home
    }

    // or else
    // display login form here 

}
```

Of course is always better to use third party login library like this one https://github.com/DaBourz/SimpleLoginSecure

Answer (score 1):

A couple of comments:

1. On the `$this->session->set_userdata('islogin');` line, you should pass a 2nd argument which is the value to be assigned (presumably, TRUE is what you meant to put)
2. I think your redirect lines are the wrong way around. If the user isn't logged in, then you want to redirect to login. Now what your code does is redirect to home if the user isn't logged in, hence the endless loop (since this code is in the home page!
3. The `$this->session->set_userdata('islogin', TRUE);` line should obviously be in your login controller, but I'm guessing you've put it here just for testing purposes?

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to access the controller, that is the point of them to control things. If you have specific functions you don't want accessed via URL then prefix the function name with an _ like _notForPublicFunction. As to the infinite refresh...

```
if(!$this->session->userdata('isLogin'))
{
    redirect('c_login');
} else {
    redirect('c_home');
}
```

Comment: do i need to rename all the `controller()` into `_controller()` ? i think it would be fine as `controller` but i want everybody has to be logged in to access all of the controller

Comment: No that is for function names not file names. Make a basic controller, then make another controller for users who are logged in, you'll have to add security to the controller and the pages to check for the session though.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is set up a base controller that will look after the session for you and split your logged in controllers from your logged out ones via inheritance.

It is a common question on here how best to manage logged-in and logged-out states. Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12486869/568884) for detailed explanation on how to do it.